# How to use two instances of a base class from a derived class

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

I want to use two instances of a base class from one derived class. I am not sure if the following code is technically correct or if there is a better way. Can the two instances mix up in any situation?

The base class A is intended to perform a common task: "changevar" which changes the variable "var" to "dv". The derived class B use this method but with two variables "var1", "var2" to change it to "dv1", and "dv2" respectively. class B then performs an "operation" over the changed variables "var1", and "var2" and return the result (in this case multiply).

````
test.py:
class A:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

    def changevar(self, dv):
        self.var = self.var + dv

    def getvar(self):
        return self.var

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        A.__init__(self, var1)
        self.inst1 = A(self.var)
        A.__init__(self, var2)
        self.inst2 = A(self.var)

    def operation(self):
        dv1 = 2
        dv2 = -2
        self.inst1.changevar(dv1)
        self.inst2.changevar(dv2)
        self.var1 = self.inst1.getvar()
        self.var2 = self.inst2.getvar()
        return self.var1, self.var2, self.var1 * self.var2

def main():
    test = B(10, 10)
    v1, v2, v3 = test.operation()
    print (v1, v2, v3)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()```

>>>python3 test.py
>>>12 8 96
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you're not actually using the inheritance.

When you execute `self.inst1 = A(self.var)` you are creating a whole new instace of A, which is different from that which is the base for your B, and assigning it to a field.

Good news are: you don't need inheritance in your case. what you need (and de-facto do) is composition - having fields of type A in your type B.

Just remove A as a base from B at all, and use the inner fields of this type, the result will be the same:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

    def changevar(self, dv):
        self.var = self.var + dv

    def getvar(self):
        return self.var

class B:
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.inst1 = A(var1)
        self.inst2 = A(var2)

    def operation(self):
        dv1 = 2
        dv2 = -2
        self.inst1.changevar(dv1)
        self.inst2.changevar(dv2)

        var1 = self.inst1.getvar()
        var2 = self.inst2.getvar()
        return var1, var2, var1 * var2

def main():
    test = B(10, 10)
    v1, v2, v3 = test.operation()
    print (v1, v2, v3)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Inheritance should be used when you want to use instances of type B as if they were of type A (e.g., call A's methods on instances of type B).
Generally we say that B should inherit from A, ib B "is-a" A - e.g. a Dog is an Animal, a Square is a Shape.
Composition is more of "has-a" relationship, like a Car has a Radio

I hope I made it clear, it's a little hard to grasp that reasoning with meaningless class names like A and B :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It solves my problem for the time being and additionally became familiar with the concept of composition.